# wpa_supplicant commands on openwrt

Tags: openwrt, wpa-supplicant, hostapd

I'm trying to port a program to openwrt. Everything works fine except wpa_supplicant. I have connected to it using wpa_cli and i have discover that for many commands such as 'scan', 'scan_results', 'add_network', etc it returns UNKNOWN COMMAND instead of the expected result.

I have seen that there is also a package with a subset of the features, but doesn't seem to be the case.

Has anybody had the same problem?

thanks!